# Tweet counter button showing zero (Addthis plugin for blogspot)

Tags: twitter, blogger

I have added a Addthis plugin for blogspot for social networking sharing. The tweet count button for some reason is showing zero always, though the link has been tweeted multiple times. 
I have verified using http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=

My blog website is http://rohit-cricket.blogspot.in/2012/10/turning-twenty-three-and-counting.html
There is no point of pasting code here, as Addthis expands when the page is loaded. It can be seen using Inspect element of google chrome.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Twitter describes a couple possibilities as to why your count may not be incrementing:

> To improve performance we cache the count before displaying it. The cache is updated frequently but on some occasions it may look like your count is not increasing while the cache is updated. In addition, the count only includes public Tweets meaning a Tweet from a protected account will not cause an increase.
>
> Additionally, there is currently a requirement that your server support HTTP HEAD requests in order to update the count properly. An easy way to check this is to use the command-line curl program, passing the -I (capital i) flag. A successful request should have a HTTP 200 OK response

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button/faq#count-api-increment

Also, try updating the link to tweet:

```
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"  tw:counturl="http://yoururltocount.com/">
```

Found answer here: http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=30188

Comment: Twitter count seems right for most of other links in the blog. Btw how long before the cache gets updated ! Two weeks, and no signs of the counter increasing above 0 !

Comment: They don't say specifically but I imagine it's not longer than 30 minutes. You may need to update your add this link for twitter to include the property tw:counturl="http://urlyouwantcounted.com", See my updated answer above.

Comment: I tried using tw:counturl='<data:blog.url />' but it was showing an error. I did this so that link gets updated for each page

Comment: Try hardcoding the URL to test as `<a class="addthis_button_tweet"  tw:counturl="http://google.com/">` and see if the counter is at least working for google.com. If it is, then you know your custom URL is not formatted properly.

Comment: I tried that even with my own url. It works fine. But the problem here is that the url link will be fixed. But for each post of mine there is a different link which can be retrieved using <data:blog.url/> . But it seems counturl cant process < tag

Comment: You probably want to open a new question for `<data:blog.url/>` not being processed properly. Is that a ColdFusion tag or something? Either way, you'll probably get an answer fast if you post that specific question as a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it. The solution is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393829/dealing-with-in-twcounturl-addthis-plugin/13409896