# Dealing with < in tw:counturl addthis plugin

Tags: blogger, addthis, blogspot

I have an addthis plugin for displaying total number of tweets in my blogspot blog.  I use it this way 
If i mention tw:counturl="my_specific_blogger_url" > it shows the exact number of tweets. But the problem is that in that case I can use only one link.
To retrieve specific blog page url I use `<data:blog.url/>`. But if i use it in tw:counturl in the following way:

`tw:counturl="<data:blog.url/>"` it shows as an error as tw:counturl cannot handle '<' tag. Is there a work around.

The error is as follows `The value of attribute "tw:counturl" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.`

Comment: How are you embedding the addthis plugin into your site? Are you using a widget (if so, what type)?

Comment: shouldn't that be `tw:counturl="<data:blog.url/>"`?

Comment: @arminrosu Yes I tried that too. It doesnt work :(

Comment: @arminrosu I have edited the question. Please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to it.
You have to add a javascript code to handle it.

```
var tweet_button = document.getElementById(&#39;addthis_button_tweet&#39;);
tweet_button.setAttribute(&#39;tw:counturl&#39;, <data:blog.url/>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you just need to add "expr" before tw:counturl. I was able to get it working on my Blogger site with the following:

```
<a class='addthis_button_tweet' expr:tw:counturl='data:blog.url'/>
```

This needs to be entered into the template itself Template -> Edit HTML -> Proceed.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: it works, but the problem is if i refresh the page, sometimes it shows 0, sometimes it shows the right number. Why does it happen? Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a page that I could take a look at? The number of shares is retrieved when the page is loaded and defaults to 0, so it might not be done loading.